# Echo form submit to div using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok, I'm not a AJAX specialist so please hear me out...

I'm trying to echo some data to a div using a form submit, AJAX and PHP. I hope this is possible. I've looked around stackoverflow and google for an answer but could not find one for my purpose.

This is my HTML:

```
<article id="search-results">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[searchandfilter id="15"]');?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[searchandfilter id="15" show="results"]'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div id="txtHint">
                    <h4>Saved Items</h4>
                    <!-- ECHO OUTPUT -->
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

In the div `txtHint` is where I want to have the output echoed. This is my form code:

```
<form id="ajaxform" class="content-items">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="thumbnail-content-items">
         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
           <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
           <?php endif; ?>
       </div>
     </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
     <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
       <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); ?>

       <div class="text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-attribute="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-whatever="<?php the_title(); ?>">Save this item <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is my AJAX script:

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.com/reload.php",
      data: "id=" + a_href,
       success: function(data, textStatus) {
        $(".txtHint").html(data);    
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Not OKay');
        }
   });

   return false;
});
```

This is in my php file:

```
<?php echo hello; ?>
```

There is something happening, the page is refreshed but this could also be the submit action from the form. Could any one help me get this to work?

Cheers

Comment: As you have return false in the jquery so this page refresh will not be through submit function. Try to console something and check the result in the console log

Comment: Google web console doesn't give any errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$(".txtHint").html(data);
```

To

```
$("#txtHint").html(data);
```

As, `txtHint` is ID not Class.

See, may be `hello` get printed. But, due to page-reload, `<div id='txtHint'>` is not able to show `ajax response`. So, you have to use `event.preventDefault();` for stopping page refresh.

Use the given code as it is. I removed `data` as you also don't know why it is used as you copied it from somewhere.

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.com/reload.php",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#txtHint").html(data);    
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Not OKay');
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

And here, put `hello` in quotes.

**reload.php**

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

Comment: I used your code, nothing is echoed. But this is what web console gave me: `POST 
XHR 
example.com/reload.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 27ms]`

Comment: `hello` is printed or not? Have you used my whole code or not? And, yes. It is working @Steggie

Comment: Page refresh is not stopped it still refreshes. Or at least my fav icon turns in to a spinner and then returns regular.

Hello is not printed, i copied your code from here and paste it to my texteditor

Comment: Ha Ha `:D` Check my updated answer. Read carefully. @Steggie

Comment: Well hello there my printed Hello!

It works! Thanks Nana! Now I have to find out how to echo my session in there. But this is a HUGE step in the right direction!

Comment: Do you perhaps know why all my items work. Except the bottom one? Is there some last-child at work here? When I press this submit button the page refresh is still going strong with this one @Nana Partykar

Comment: `bottom one` means `return false;`? `event.preventDefault();` will handle all those. But, declare `event` in `submit(function(event){`. @Steggie

Comment: Could you please update your code? I'm pretty new to AJAX @Nana Partykar

Comment: Same code @Steggie. Nothing added newly. use same code and check `submit(function(event){` is written properly or not.

Comment: Im really sorry about this but where can I check this? @ Nana Partykar

Comment: Ha Ha `:D` @Steggie. Be Calm Dear. No Worries. Your code only. Check `event` is available in this line `$("#ajaxform").submit(function(event){` or not?

Comment: I think so `$(".ajaxform").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();` @Nana Partykar. I just copied your code and pasted in to mine. Also I had to make it a class because it repeats its self over 1 page.

Comment: @Steggie : What was the problem? And, How You Rectified It? Please Share. *~Thanks. Glad To Help*

Comment: The problem was the placement of the script. It needed to be placed somewhere else then where I originally placed it (below the session id). I don't know why, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use instead of

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(){

"id=" + a_href,
```

Into

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

{id : a_href},
```

Comment: Like this?

`$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({`

Comment: Nope, nothing happens... Web console doesn't give any errors as well.

Comment: what is this "a_href"?

Comment: I don't know it was in the code...  I copied from an other site. I tried your code: `$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "example.com/reload.php",
      data: {id : a_href},
       success: function(data, textStatus) {
        $(".txtHint").html(data);    
     },
     error: function() {
         alert('Not OKay');
     }
   });

   return false;
});`

Again nothing

Comment: I changed my reload.php file to `<?php echo hello; ?>` so I could know its an easy echo

Comment: And also changed '"id=" + a_href,' into '{id : 1}' and let me know

Comment: @Steggie: Is page reloading after submit?

Comment: $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "example.com/reload.php", data: {id : 1}, success: function(data, textStatus) { $(".txtHint").html(data); }, error: function() { alert('Not OKay'); } });}); use this. Please change the url as (your site)

Comment: @Nana Partykar, Yes. When I click on the submit button `type=submit` the page is reloaded.

@Maths RkBala, Still no go. I removed the ' ' marks from your {id:1}

Comment: @Maths RkBala, Your last code also did nothing. (I will thank you for your effort so far!)

Comment: Welcome It's Okay :-(

Comment: Ok I haven't seen this one before. I placed the code somewhere else and my console gave me this:

`GET 
XHR 
example/reload.php /reload.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 49ms]
GET 
XHR 
example/reload.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 44ms]`

hover link is `example/reload.php?id=1` There is something hapeing...